# Crash RubyInline when I include '<algorithm>' and '<vector>'

Tags: c++, ruby

I don't understand why RubyInline is crashing.

```
class CPPCode
    inline do |builder|
        builder.include '<algorithm>'
        builder.include '<vector>'
        builder.c 'int test(){return 1;}'
    end
end
```

The error:

> error executing "gcc -shared -fPIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -fPIC -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -I /home/lionzxy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I /home/lionzxy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I /home/lionzxy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include -L/home/lionzxy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib -o \"/home/lionzxy/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_Book__CPPCode_232b56c4fe2ef7959c8f3c1f6db3cebb.so\" \"/home/lionzxy/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_Book__CPPCode_232b56c4fe2ef7959c8f3c1f6db3cebb.c\" ": pid 24454 exit 1 Renamed /home/lionzxy/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_Book__CPPCode_232b56c4fe2ef7959c8f3c1f6db3cebb.c to /home/lionzxy/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.3.0/Inline_Book__CPPCode_232b56c4fe2ef7959c8f3c1f6db3cebb.c.bad

Generated C++ file:

```
#include "ruby.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

# line 58 "/home/lionzxy/RubymineProjects/app/models/book.rb"
static VALUE test(VALUE self) {
return INT2FIX(1);}


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void Init_Inline_Book__CPPCode_098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6() {
    VALUE c = rb_cObject;
    c = rb_const_get(c, rb_intern("Book"));
    c = rb_const_get(c, rb_intern("CPPCode"));

    rb_define_method(c, "test", (VALUE(*)(ANYARGS))test, 0);

}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use C++ code, but you're running `gcc` without any flags to tell it that it's C++ code.

On the [first documentation page](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/RubyInline/3.12.4) we see an example on how to use C++ code:

```
require 'inline'
class MyTest
    inline(:C) do |builder|
        builder.include '<iostream>'
        builder.add_compile_flags '-x c++', '-lstdc++'
        builder.c '
            void hello(int i) {
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
                }
            }'
    end
end

t = MyTest.new()
t.hello(3)
```

The "trick" here is:

```
builder.add_compile_flags '-x c++', '-lstdc++'
```

which tells `gcc` that this is C++ code.